# Neo4j: full text search with multiple search terms

Tags: neo4j, full-text-search, cypher

I have configured my full text search in Neo4j and  indexed two fields.

```
START n=node:node_auto_index("val1:*1*") RETURN n
union 
START n=node:node_auto_index("val2:*1*") RETURN n;
```

It works but Is there any better way to do this. Also can I search in all the indexes at once?

Comment: Looks like no valid answers